# Use mutate and dynamically named variables in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to apply a function that selects the best transformation of certain variables in a data frame, and then adds new columns to the data frame with the transformed data. I can currently get the transformation to run as follows. However, this rewrites the existing data, instead of adding new, transformed variables. I have seen the other stackoverflow posts about dynamically-added variables but can't quite seem to get it to work. Here is what I have:

```
df <- data.frame(study_id = c(1:10),
                 v1 = (sample(1:100, 10)),
                 v2 = (sample(1:100, 10)),
                 v3 = (sample(1:100, 10)),
                 v4 = (sample(1:100, 10)))

require(bestNormalize)

transformed <- function(x) {
  bn <- bestNormalize(x)
  return(bn$x.t)
}

df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(c(2,4:5), transformed))
```

Current output:

```
   study_id           v1 v2         v3          v4
1         1 -0.001846842 43  0.6559159  0.37893888
2         2 -2.416625847 81 -1.2998111 -0.64356058
3         3  1.012132345 95 -1.5086228 -0.48845289
4         4  0.798561562  2  0.8301299  0.30168982
5         5 -0.257460026 35  0.1322051  0.78737617
6         6 -0.179681789 42 -1.1352463 -2.42438347
7         7  0.378206706 22 -0.3635088  0.79583687
8         8  0.909304988 70  1.0748401  0.63712357
9         9  0.325879668 32  0.9041796 -0.09711216
10       10 -0.568470765  7  0.7099185  0.75254380
```

Desired output:

```
   study_id  v1 v2 v3  v4 v1_transformed v3_transformed v4_transformed
1         1  72  7 87 100              4              3              2
2         2  57 78 64  69             10              8              6
3         3  35 65 83  96              3              5              4
4         4  24 58 94  53              6             10             10
5         5 100 62 82  63             -1              7              3
6         6  47 55  4  50              8              4              1
7         7  83 97 35  41              7              2             -1
8         8  78 86 22  73              1             -1              9
9         9  11 39 93  68              2              0              7
10       10  36 49  8  72              0              1              0
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `require` should be used within an `if(...)`   If you are just using it bare then library is preferred so that it signals an error immediately if the package is not found rather than have the error signaled later when it will be harder to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.names=` argument of `across`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(2,4:5), transformed, .names = "{.col}_transformed"))
```

giving:

```
   study_id v1 v2 v3 v4 v1_transformed v3_transformed v4_transformed
1         1 50 72 12  7      0.3850197     -0.7916019     -1.9775107
2         2 53 82 61 42      0.4425318      0.6132865      0.6790496
3         3  3 12 90 20     -2.3661268      0.9496526     -0.4232995
4         4 20 84 37 21     -0.5190229      0.1809655     -0.3508475
5         5 55 54  4 23      0.4790925     -1.7301008     -0.2157362
6         6 61 96 85 74      0.5812924      0.9002185      1.5209888
7         7 52 94 22 38      0.4237308     -0.2683955      0.5302984
8         8 72 41 57 35      0.7449435      0.5546340      0.4080778
9         9 13 67  6 45     -0.9434502     -1.3866702      0.7815968
10       10 74 48 93 14      0.7719892      0.9780114     -0.9526174
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the quick response! Works perfectly.

Comment: I'd advise you be a little careful with this, as `bestNormalize()` is stochastic (since it uses repeated CV). Just make sure to set the seed prior to running this or choose an in-sample normalization statistic.